# Execute C# interactive powershell scripts

Tags: c#, powershell

Suppose i execute a powershell script using C#. The result of the script execution is that credentials are requested in order to continue.

Example:

```
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
... = pipeline.Invoke();
// i must enter credentials in order to continue the script execution
```

Is it possible to implement this kind of interaction programmatically?

Comment: What interaction? You mean the credential prompt? That's what happens when you *don't* fill the `-Credentials` property of a commandlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way IMO is to connect to the target computer with valid credentials, then you can execute any code without any credential prompts, To do that, You need to create a `PSCredential` object, which is a Username and a SecureString Password.

To convert plain text to SecureString you can use this method:

```
private SecureString GetSecurePassword(string password)
        {
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            return securePassword;
        }
```

Then your next step is to create a `WSManConnectionInfo` object for the target computer, and add the Credentials, again you can use this method:

```
WSManConnectionInfo GetConnectionInfo(string computerName)
        {
            PSCredential creds = new PSCredential("UserName",
              GetSecurePassword("Password"));

            Uri remoteComputerUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:5985/wsman", computerName));
            WSManConnectionInfo connection = new WSManConnectionInfo(remoteComputerUri,
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell",
                creds);

            return connection;
        }
```

Finally, connect to the target computer and create a Runspace:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = GetConnectionInfo("computerName");
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
```

And back to your code:

```
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpfull! :)