# WSManConnectionInfo and PSCredential for Runspace Powershell Commands as Another User

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been trying to figure out how to enable Runspace Powershell commands to run as another user and I've found examples such as [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?556741-Run-Powershell-commands-inside-Winform-C-with-another-users-crfedential):

```
var con = new WSManConnectionInfo();
con.Credential = new PSCredential("user", "pass".ToSecureString());
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(con);
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.Add("dir");
pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
var results = pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
```

However this does not work, because `con.Credential` is a read only property. I don't know how this guy could claim it works.

When I try doing it differently:

```
var cred = new PSCredential(objWINS + "\\" + objUser, objPW.ToSecureString());
var con = new WSManConnectionInfo(cred);
```

The `WSManConnectionInfo` class wants more information such as a Uri and a Shell string. I'm just trying to run Powershell commands here, there's no Uri I need to connect to, I have no idea what the shell is for either and the only thing I can find in searches is this URL:

"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell"

There is not a lot of info out there on this class, nothing that I can really glean any info on what to add as the Uri at least.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you specify Credentials for the `WSManConnectionInfo` object:

```
WSManConnectionInfo GetConnectionInfo(string computerName)
        {
            PSCredential creds = new PSCredential("UserName",
              GetSecurePassword("Password"));

            Uri remoteComputerUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:5985/wsman", computerName));
            WSManConnectionInfo connection = new WSManConnectionInfo(remoteComputerUri,
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell",
                creds);

            return connection;
        }
```

For more detailed information see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787381/execute-c-sharp-interactive-powershell-scripts/46787714#46787714) (with the `GetSecurePassword` method)

Comment: But why do I have to set `remoteComputerUri` when I'm trying to access my local machine?
If I have to - should I set up wsman before?

Comment: it's just a name, you can change it from remote to local :)