# Invoke-Command on Hyper-V VM Powershell C#

Tags: c#, powershell, hyper-v

I am trying but failing in every way to invoke a command on Hyper-V managed VM via C# / Powershell. I can run various other PS commands without any issue, plus I can also run the Invoke-Command directly in Powershell cmd.

My main aim will be to run / execute remote processes on the VMs. I am currently using a script block to {Get-Childitem C:\Windows} to list the directories, just to get some output for testing.

In Powershell if I run:

```
Invoke-Command -VMName Windows10 -ScriptBlock {Get-Childitem C:\\Windows}
```

It works after being prompted with credentials.

My C# code that fails and I have tried numerous ways to get this working with no avail.

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        var scBlock = ScriptBlock.Create("{Get-Childitem C:\\Windows}");
        
        // Create a PSCredential
        var cred = CreateCredential("test", "test");

        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
            runspace.Open();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            ps.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
            ps.AddParameter("VMName", "Windows10");
            ps.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", scBlock);
            ps.AddParameter("Credential", cred);

            ps.Streams.Progress.DataAdded += (sender, ev) =>
            {
                var progressRecords = (PSDataCollection<ProgressRecord>)sender;
                Console.WriteLine("Progress is {0} percent complete",
                    progressRecords[ev.Index].PercentComplete);
            };
            ps.Streams.Warning.DataAdded += (sender, ev) =>
            {
                var warnings = (PSDataCollection<WarningRecord>)sender;
                var message = warnings[ev.Index].Message;
                Console.WriteLine($"WARNING - {message}");
            };
            ps.Streams.Error.DataAdded += (sender, ev) =>
            {
                var error = (PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>)sender;
                var message = error[ev.Index].Exception?.Message;
                Console.WriteLine($"ERROR - {message}");
            };

            try
            {
                var results = ps.Connect();
                foreach (var tPsObject in results)
                {
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the following errors in the console:

```
ERROR - Configuration system failed to initialize
ERROR - The input VMName Windows10 does not resolve to a single virtual machine.
```

I am only using Powershell within C# as it seems to be the easiest/most common way to manage Hyper-V virtual machines.

A side question, is there a way to run all of the above from a non-elevated process. E.g I don't want to run my application as Administrator.

Comment: it's not really related to Hyper-V, but generally execute commands remotely using PSSession in c#, so instead of writing this allover see my other answer with better implementation IMO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787381/execute-c-sharp-interactive-powershell-scripts/46787714#46787714